# PHP redirection with parameter forwarding

Tags: php, url, redirect, http-redirect, forwarding

I am using the following PHP script in order to create redirects :

```
<?php
 
$id     = isset( $_GET['id'] ) ? rtrim( trim( $_GET['id'] ), '/' ) : 'default';
$f  = fopen( 'redirects.txt', 'r' );
$urls   = array();
 
// The file didn't open correctly.
if ( !$f ) {
    echo 'Make sure you create your redirects.txt file and that it\'s readable by the redirect script.';
    die;
}
 
// Read the input file and parse it into an array
while( $data = fgetcsv( $f ) ) {
    if ( !isset( $data[0] ) || !isset( $data[1] ) )
        continue;
    
    $key = trim( $data[0] );
    $val = trim( $data[1] );
    $urls[ $key ] = $val;
}
 
// Check if the given ID is set, if it is, set the URL to that, if not, default
$url = ( isset( $urls[ $id ] ) ) ? $urls[ $id ] : ( isset( $urls[ 'default' ] ) ? $urls[ 'default' ] : false );

if ( $url ) {
    header( "X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow", true );
    header( "Location: " .  $url, 302 );
    die;    
} else {
    echo '<p>Make sure yor redirects.txt file contains a default value, syntax:</p>
    <pre>default,http://example.com</pre>
    <p>Where you should replace example.com with your domain.</p>';
}
```

It works well except that URL parameters (example : `domaine.com/redirect/target-url?param=abc` are not forwarded... And I'd like them to be forwared.

How can I amend this code so URL parameters are forwarded ?

Comment: It depends on if your `$url` ever contains GET already. But if it doesn't, you can do something like `header( "Location: " .  $url.'?'.http_build_query($_GET), 302 );`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query string using `http_build_query()` and feed it an array of key => values. Using `$_GET` would forward all the parameters:

```
$params = http_build_query($_GET);
$url = $url.'?'.$params;
```

If you need to remove some params (ie `id`), you can create a copy of `$_GET` and then unset the items you don't want forwarded:

```
$params = $_GET;
unset($params['id']);
$url = $url.'?'.http_build_query($params);
```